# moving my app from Windows to Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

when moving my app from Windows to Ubuntu I get
      com.google.gson.JsonParseException: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "13:31:16 13/04/2010"

I think it is related to my regional settings . currently my windows system are set on hebrew and on ubuntu i have

locale

LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`13/04/2010` is likely at fault there: as your `LC_TIME` has `en_US` (English, U.S.A.), the system may be expecting the date to be in `mm/dd/yyyy` format, and Undecimber (the 13th month) may be a bit hard to process ;)

Maybe you want to set your locale to `he_IL`? (possibly through the Language settings dialog)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your quick reply. I am new to unbuntu . how do I change locale ? is there a gui option to do that ?

Comment: @user450602: System > Administration > Language Support > Install/remove languages http://www.futuredesktop.org/maverick/images/picture-5a.png ; I'm sure Hebrew is in that list.

Comment: Hey thanks. did it. now I can see he file next to en in /var/lib/locales/supported.d but I still get the same exception . I think it still tries to parse the data according to the en version

Comment: I think you need to 1) drag Hebrew to be above English in the locale list, and 2) log off and on again for the settings to take effect.

Comment: Sorry , I still get the exception